# Get a CookieContainer from a WebBrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, http, cookies, webbrowser-control

First of all, excuse me If I misunderstood some concepts, since web requests and cookies are not my fort.

Well, the thing is that I would like to get all the cookies stored in the **WebBrowser**'s session for the current url. This will help me for example after interactively logging in a website, I can retrieve the cookies from the WebBrowser instance to use them in background with the **HttpWebRequest** class. (the website has security measures like a captcha and a random question, so for me is not viable to try automate it using requests in background to login and store the cookies, I prefer to use a webbrowser)

This is what I tried so far, it seems that it works fine but I'm not sure whether I did it all ok without missing any important thing to take into account, and I think my approach seems a little dirty solution, I mean maybe exists a direct way to get this from the abstraction layer of the **WebBrowser** control...

```
<HideModuleName>
Public Module WebBrowserExtensions

    <Extension>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function GetCookieContainer(ByVal wb As WebBrowser) As CookieContainer
        Dim uri As Uri = wb.Url
        Dim cookieContainer As New CookieContainer()
        Dim cookies As String() = wb.Document.Cookie.Split({";"c}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        For Each cookie As String In cookies
            Dim name As String = cookie.Substring(0, cookie.IndexOf("="c)).TrimStart(" "c)
            Dim value As String = cookie.Substring(cookie.IndexOf("="c) + 1)
            cookieContainer.Add(uri, New Cookie(name, value, "/", uri.Host))
        Next cookie

        Return cookieContainer
    End Function

End Module
```

So, my question is: It is all ok with my approach?, if not then which would be the proper way to do this?.

PS: I know the **WebBrowser** is a embedded instance of **Internet Explorer**, but I'm not sure about how the `WebBrowser` manages the cookies, I mean if the cookies persists only during the lifetime of the current application or the **WebBrowser** instance, or just the cookies are stored in the system and are the same cookies used by **Internet Explorer**. As I said, excuse me If I misunderstood some concepts.